# Open AI Gym, Agent not following the specified action in Frozen Lake Simulation

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I have an agent trained on the Frozen Lake simulation from Open AI Gym. Based on the Frozen Lake code, I see that the actions correspond to the following numbers:

```
LEFT = 0
DOWN = 1
RIGHT = 2
UP = 3
```

The agent is initialized at state 0 (top-left) corner of the 4 x 4 grid.

[image]

However, when I direct the agent to move left (technically it can't) with the value 0 as seen in the code below, I presume that the agent should remain in the same position.

```
action = 0 # Left
env.reset()
new_state, reward, done, info = env.step(action) # Take a step
```

However, it moved down to state 4 as seen in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. There's an argument called slippery_slope which designates the probability that the agent will follow the instruction. It's specified in the frozen_lake.py file:

```
`is_slippery`: True/False. If True will move in intended direction with
probability of 1/3 else will move in either perpendicular direction with
equal probability of 1/3 in both directions.
```

Setting the argument to false corrected the issue with the inconsistent state change given a specified action.